# Unable to fill JavaFX ComboBox on runtime

Tags: combobox, javafx

I am doing a project where I have to fill a ComboBox with attributes from objects the user has just stored in a Hashmap before. This means I cannot assign the Items to the ComboBox in advance. This is the first time I am trying to use javaFX. So far it was ok, but when I try to fill the ComboBox "loggedOnUsersDropDown", nothing happens. It just stays empty. I created the UI including the ComboBox with scene builder. The code of the method looks like this:

```
@FXML
protected void loadLoggedOn(){
    ArrayList<String> loggedOn = new ArrayList();

    for (User LOGGED_Onkey : bd.currentSSO.LOGGED_ON.keySet()) {
        loggedOn.add(LOGGED_Onkey.getAttribute(LOGGED_Onkey.USER_NAME));          //System.out.println(LOGGED_Onkey.getAttribute(LOGGED_Onkey.USER_NAME));
    }

    ObservableList<String> obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(loggedOn);
    //loggedOnUsersDropDown.getItems().clear();
    loggedOnUsersDropDown = new ComboBox<String>();
    loggedOnUsersDropDown.getItems().addAll(obList);
    System.out.println(loggedOn.size());
}
```

I would appreciate any answer. Thanks in advance and soory if i forgot some important information.

Comment: You're creating a new combo box. Do you ever add the new one to the scene graph?

Comment: No i dont. I was thinking that javafx is handling that for me since the combobox was created in scene bulilder. Thanks for the hint. I seem to be unable to add the combobox to anything, for example the line "root.getChildren().add(loggenOnUsersDropDown)" does not work., any hints on how to add the combobox correctly ? thanks

Comment: Why create a new combo box?

Comment: Because i have to fill it dynamically. i do not have the Strings i need in the box in advance. is there another option to fill the existing one ?

Comment: I just realized that the scene builder is not able to find the field for my Combobox. Although it is initialized like so : @FXML 
 ComboBox loggedOnUsersDropDown. Everything else which is initialized like this seems to be working fine. thanks for any answer.

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your FXML and the declaration of the `ComboBox` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `ComboBox` and populating it. That `ComboBox` is not a part of your scene graph, so you don't see the result of populating it.

Assuming the `@FXML` injection is set up correctly, you should be able to just remove the line

```
loggedOnUsersDropDown = new ComboBox<String>();
```

and it will work correctly.

Comment: I tried that. For some reason i get a NullPointerExeption. I assume there is something wrong with the @FXML injection. Also the scene Builder does not seem to regognize the injection Field. But like i said, everything else is working perfectly. Thank you very much for your help ;)

Comment: So edit your question to include the relevant parts of the FXML file (definition of the combo box) and the declaration of the combo box in the controller.